# VS marca como error la sintaxis <> para un fragment

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017

```
return <>
        <NavItem>
            <NavLink href={`/app/logout?returnUrl=${returnUrl}`}>Log out</NavLink>
        </NavItem>
</>
```

Tengo el anterior fragmento de codigo dentro de un archivo tsx, en una carpeta en visual studio. El mismo reconoce esta clase de archivos (les puso el icono) y hasta tengo intellisense para las clases y metodos.

Sin embargo, no reconoce el fragment como tal, y tira un error en la IDE. Sin embargo el codigo compila y corre sin problemas al hacer npm start.

Por lo tanto, es un problema de la IDE

Haciendo

```
return <React.Fragment>
        <NavItem>
            <NavLink href={`/app/logout?returnUrl=${returnUrl}`}>Log out</NavLink>
        </NavItem>
</React.Fragment>
```

No tira error en la IDE. La pregunta es, como le digo a mi IDE que este codigo esta bien? (o es un bug de VS?)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema se da porque el SDK para typescript, no esta embebido en la instalacion de Visual Studio, y debe instalarse por separado. Por defecto, viene instalado un paquete anterior a la version 2.5 de Ts, el cual no contenia como valido el tag `<>`.

Para solucionar este problema, hay que bajar de la [pagina de microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258) el ultimo paquete e instalarlo. Al reiniciar Visual Studio, el problema estara resuelto.